# How do I download the video & audio files in my expo app?

Tags: react-native, youtube, expo, file-manager

I want to download the audio and video content which is seen in my app (In app download) just like we download the videos in youtube and can be watched offline. I also want the downloaded content to not show in my file manager and gallery.

I researched about downloading the files but dont have an idea about how to show only in app and no where else like youtube.

Answer (score -1):

Well here is some working code (at least for me) that can download a file.

In the `const result`, you just have to replace `http://www.example.com/` with your file; this means that if it is a video, this link should lead to that video.

And that's it for now; all is set when you run the app using '*npx expo start*' you will see a 'download' button  that will ask for storage permission; once you allow it, you should be able to see the video.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { shareAsync } from 'expo';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const VideoMaker = () => {
  async function download() {
    const filename = "dummy.mp4";
    const result = await FileSystem.downloadAsync('http://somesite.com/', FileSystem.documentDirectory + filename);

    // Log the download result
    console.log(result);

    // Save the downloaded file
    saveFile(result.uri, filename, result.headers["Content-Type"]);
  }

  async function saveFile(uri, filename, mimetype) {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      const permissions = await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();

      if (permissions.granted) {
        const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });

        await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, filename, mimetype)
          .then(async (uri) => {
            await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, base64, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
          })
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      } else {
        shareAsync(uri);
      }
    } else {
      shareAsync(uri);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={download}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Download</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});

export default VideoMaker;
```